# Creating a Sharepoint workflow to gather data for a custom list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-list, powerapps

I have a custom list in Sharepoint with lots of choice columns which a user must select. There are also numeric and text columns and although there are up to thirty columns, they are semantically grouped into three types of data (just columns in the list though).

e.g

```
"personal type"
Age -> choice (Old,Young)
Grade -> number
Comments -> text

"operation type"
Procedure -> choice (select one from up to 10 different choices)
Grade -> number
Comments -> text
```

I tried a Power App but the choice columns don't work in Power Apps so I was wondering if it's possible to design a Sharepoint workflow to:

- select type (personal, operation, etc)
- once type is selected, gather data to populate those columns in the list
- when all types are complete, send emails to key personnel

So the workflow would need to ask the user which type they wanted to work on, then display the columns from the list for that type and allow the user to enter the data, allow the user to "save" i.e. move back to the main screen and select the next type until all types have had their data entered.

Programmatic is fine as I'm a developer but I'm new to sharepoint so hoping to learn from more experienced workflow/power app designers. Power app would ideal if it supported choice columns but I'm not sure it can segregate screen based on the type of data, i.e. display a list of types and then display the screen containing only data for the type selected.

Answer (score 0):

Since I asked this question I found out creating a blank tablet Power App and then adding the DataSource allows use of choice columns from the Sharepoint list. Creating a phone Power App from a Sharepoint custom list doesn't allow use of choice columns. So the solution is to start from scratch in Power Apps and build the screens myself, rather than relying on Power Apps to auto build where it doesn't support choice columns